# POSTGRES バインド値を、同SQL内の別の箇所でも使用したい

Tags: sql

現在の実装は下記の通りです

```html
SELECT
  CASE 'バインド値' 
    WHEN 'ABC' THEN "none"
    ELSE NEXTVAL('☆') 
    END AS VALUE;
```

CASEの判定値にバインド値を設定しており、そのバインド値を「☆」の部分でも使用したいのですが方法がわかりません。
分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from内でバインド値を取得すれば、select内で使いまわすことが出来ます。

```html
from (select 'バインド値' as BIND_VALUE) as BIND
```

取得するときは、

```html
BIND.BIND_VALUE
```

で取得することが出来ます。

Answer (score 2):

手元のPostgres環境では次のようなSQLで動作しました。

```
SELECT
  CASE seq_names.name 
    WHEN 'ABC' THEN 'none'
    ELSE CAST(NEXTVAL(seq_names.name) AS VARCHAR)
    END AS VALUE
FROM
  (SELECT CAST('blogs_id_seq' AS VARCHAR) AS name) seq_names
```

適宜CASTをしないと型の不一致でエラーが出るようです。

Comment: 私の環境下ではエラーが出ないので、バージョンによる影響などがありそうですが、CASTする方が丁寧ですね。